# Difference between redis.call('HMGET', key, value) and redis.hmget(key, value)?

Tags: performance, hash, redis, lua, key

Is there any notable difference, particularly from a performance perspective? Or are they effectively the same?

Comment: I have no experience with Redis but would think that `redis.hmget` (or probably generic `redis.xxx` calls as well) is a simple wrapper around `redis.call` and shouldn't almost affect performance at all.